# Access java variables from javacode to javascript code in react-native

Tags: android, variables, react-native

**I want to access a String variable present in MyActivity.java file in android code into my javascript file in react-native.**

I am accessing android ID using the code:

String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);

Now I want to access this android_id in my javascript code in react-native.

How to implement it??

Answer (score 0):

Override getLaunchOptions in your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
...
  @Override
  protected @Nullable Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    bundle.putString("android_id", android_id);
    return bundle;
  }
...
}
```

In your React root component you can now access `this.props.android_id`. From there you can pass it to anywhere you need it.

Comment: I am getting the following error after implementing above answer------error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override

Comment: Did you put the method in your MainActivity that extends ReactActivity?

Comment: Ah ok. Remove the @Override then. And in line 38 replace `null` with `getLaunchOptions()`

Comment: Now I am getting this error----error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPackages() in ReactActivity
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {